# Socket.io the best way to store user authentication

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I wonder what is the best way to authenticate a user in socket.io? I build a chat app where store all users in an array like this:

```
let sockets = [];
sockets[userdbId] = socket.id
```

There is a few problems.

```
io.on("connection", async socket => {
  
  socket.on("online", (userId, friends) => {
    sockets[userId] = socket.id;
    friends.forEach((id, index) => {
      if(sockets[id]){
        socket.to(sockets[id]).emit("friendOnline", data)}
    })
  })

  socket.on("Message", (message, userData, toUserId, callback) => {
    socket.to(sockets[toUserId]).emit("message",  {userId: userData._id, 
     userData: {userName: userData.userName,avatarUrl: userData.avatarUrl}, UserMessage: message })
      callback();
  })
})
```

-First, When a user opens a new tab react app make new connect with socket and generate different socket id so the preview tabs don't work.

-Second, My app is divided into two parts. Lobby and friend chat, I am not sure but probably I implemented it in a wrong way because friend part connects to the socket by io.connect(window.location.host) and listen for message, but the lobby part connect io(window.location.host/lobby/lobbyId) so again this kind connection change socket id.

Right now I am looking for a solution on how to make a safe and unique socket id. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I was thinking to use jwt token as authentication what do you think about this?

Comment: Why an array? If your `userdbId` values get really large this will create a gigantic array for no reason. Use an object as a hash: `let sockets = { }`;

Comment: it's just a temporary solution, I will use redis later

Comment: This is a temporary fix. If your ID values are like 2930123 that creates a *huge* array for absolutely no reason. `{}` works exactly the same, but only creates entries when necessary. Zero code changes other than that required.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I encountered a similar issue when creating one of my apps.

How I solved this was by adding firebase authentication to uniquely identify each user that logs in and logs out of my website (based of email and their unique USER uid). Hence, this prevents the random allocation of a socket.id and making it easier to identify the user every time he/she enters the website. Furthermore, the second issue you have stated could also be solved with authentication to prevent socket.id changing as the user can be identified based of its USER uid instead from the socket.uid.

Here is some documentation that may help when implementing auth: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the full functionality you need, you could consider building your app in such a way that it does not rely on a single socket connection per user. Rather, use socketIO middleware and something like JWT to auth each new connection when it connects and assign it to a user.

In the front end, once connection is established you just send an authorization packet with the JWT token, and on the backend, you receive that token, parse and validate it and
store the userId as a property of the socket, instead of storing the socket Id to the user.

```
socket.userId = userId;
```

In this way, all your later callbacks can just refer to the userId as a parameter of the socket.

```
userId = socket.userId;
```

The socket instance exists for the lifetime of the connection, so you don't need to re-auth every message, but you can if you attach the token to each message and use socket.io middleware to pre-process each message:

```js
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    // Socket Auth Middleware
    socket.use((packet, next) => {
    
      // Your authorization code goes here
      // and returns a userId if authorized
      
      // Attach the userId to the socket, which
      // will persist for the lifetime of the connection.
      socket.user = userId;
      
      // Pass to the next middleware, or to your socket 'routes'.
      return next();    
    });

   // Your socket 'online' and 'messages' callbacks here
  
   });
```

You need the **return next();** to pass the message to your routes, but of course you can just return without **next()** to kill the message entirely if it fails authentication.

Advantages:

- If a single user opens multiple chat windows, either 'friend' or 'direct' or 'both', they should work without issue and without having to sort messages on the front end. Messages for each would go just to the relevant socket.
- Sockets can sometimes drop out and reconnect. If your sockets are configured to auto-reconnect there could be a seamless recovery (assuming your socket re-auths with something like JWT).
- You can use socket.io rooms to subscribe each socket to the relevant rooms, ie: in lobby chat you would subscribe the connected socket to the lobby room id, but you can ALSO subscribe the socket to a room for the user (maybe use the userId as long as it won't conflict with room ids). This way you can send anything relevant to the user only to all of the user's connections (ie: a message notification maybe). Of course, you can still directly message a single connection using emit.

There are ways to try to ensure only one socket per user, but I'm not sure if that would benefit you in this case.

Is there any reason this approach might not work for you? I can give more details if you have some specific concerns.

Comment: it looks good every time when I emit an event from front-end, backend check if jwt is ok. But what now? How to implement emit events to individual user?

Comment: User socket.io rooms: https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Any time you authenticate a new socket connection, add that socket to a room named after the userId: socket.join(userId);

Then, use IO.to(userId).emit(event, payload) to send to that room. All sockets subscribed to that room will receive the message. Since a socket can subscribe to multiple rooms, subscribe it to any chat rooms that the user is currently in as well.

Make sense?

Comment: Additionally, you can still emit directly to that socket only using socket.emit()